# PHP Variable from one server to another

Tags: php, transfer

I am pretty new to php.

I have two websites:
Site1 has a code that counts the characters in the domain name. So I have:

```
echo count($letters);
```

This works great.
What I need is to take this variable and echo it on Site2. How can I do that? Site2 is on a different server.

Comment: take a look into curl extesion

Comment: I think we need more information here about what you're doing to understand why and how this data needs to be calculated at site 1 and outputting to site 2.

Comment: There is no direct way to allow one server to access a variable on another, you will need to code a page or service which allows them to pass information back and forth with one server sending the other the information it needs to be able to give an answer.

Comment: cURL / file_get_contents() may help u! But it's... bizarre, or i think so!

Answer (score 1):

very easy and straight forward solution is

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://ww.google.com');
echo $content;
```

and replace google link with your other server link